# What is the default sort behavior of a C++ 2D vector?

Tags: c++

When sorting a 2d vector using stl:sort(), what is its default sort behavior? I would like to know what happens if there are ties? How would the default comparator work?

Comment: The default ordering operator is plain `<`. So if you compare two elements of the outer vector using `<` and it does the right thing, then likely `std::sort` will do the right thing as well.

Comment: And for your next question, please show us a [mre] of your code, instead of describing it. Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Vector elements are compared lexicographically. Don't hesitate to read [manuals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp)

Answer (score 3):

It compares lexicographically with respect to both `std::vector` layers. That's because `std::vector::operator<` is specified to compare elements lexicographically and by default `std::sort` uses `<` to compare elements.

`std::sort` will always leave the order of equivalent elements unspecified. `std::stable_sort` will however leave the order of equivalent elements identical to their original order (and incurs a performance penalty for being able to do so).

Comment: And while `std::sort` leaves equal elements unspecified, there is also [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) which will preserve the original order of equal elements.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the others' answers, here's a simple example (may require a recent version of C++):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    auto x = vector{4,2,7};
    sort(x.begin(), x.end());
    for (auto e : x)
        cout << e << " ";
    cout << endl;

    auto y = vector{
        vector{1,123},
        vector{2,3},
        vector{3,2},
        vector{1,7},
        vector{2,3}
    };
    sort(y.begin(), y.end());
    for (auto e : y)
        cout << e[0] << "," << e[1] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```